# Reregister existing package with ghc-pkg

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I have previously installed a package with `cabal install <package>`. And I have unregistered it using `ghc-pkg unregister`. But now I want it back again.

The package binaries and source are still stored in my .cabal directory. I just need to register it again with `ghc-pkg`. But I don't find a way to do it.

I have tried:

- `ghc-pkg register ...`: To do this I need a package description file. But I don't find a way to get one from the data stored in the .cabal dir.
- `cabal install ...`: This builds the package from source, taking ages on this tiny computer.
- `cabal register`: Seems to have to do with the build process, when given the .cabal file stored in .cabal/packages/... is asks me to run `cabal configure`.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know how to do it without rebuilding, I'm afraid, once you lost the `package-id.conf`. If you have a backup of your `~/.ghc`, you can copy the `.conf` file from the backup to `~/.ghc/version/package.conf.d`, that should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is any easy way of doing that without rebuilding. If you want to use package again you should not `unregister` it as it deletes the package info from the database, instead you can `hide` the package which you can later `expose`.

The otherthing which you can do is to save the output of `ghc-pkg describe <pkg name>` and then `unregister` the pkg. Later you can do `ghc-pkg register <file where you saved describe output>`.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'll just have to be more careful with my .conf files in the future.